# the duration of a mp3 returns zero

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avurlasset

I want to get the duration of a mp3 file from the internet,I use the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://view.33591.com:586/2012/11/30/11/4207369.mp3"];    
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url
                                            options:nil];
CMTime time = asset.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
NSLog(@"seconds:%f",seconds);
```

but it always returns 0,if I change the url to a local file from the bundle,it works fine.So is there a way to do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://view.33591.com:586/2012/11/30/11/4207369.mp3"];
```

The URL you provide is not a filesystem path. Use `[NSURL URLWithString:]` instead, and **do read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBGFBJ)** of the `NSURL` class and in particular the methods you are seeking to use.

> `fileURLWithPath:`
>
> Initializes and returns a newly created NSURL object **as a file URL with a specified path.**

(emphasis mine)